# How to generate random names on particular days in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my program which generates random name:

```
 String[] names = new String[]{"one","two","three","four","five"};
 Random rd = new Random();
 int x = rd.nextInt(names.length);
```

I need it to generate the names based on last weekend check, if the generated name matches with last weekend's generated name then the program to run again to generate different name.
Ex: If "one" is generated on Saturday and "two" is generated on Sunday, then next week these two should be excluded from generation.
How can i make that check in Java?

Comment: Store which names were picked last weekend, and when you pick for this weekend, check against those values

Comment: Use HashMap to store your previous generated names as value and keys as days. Check that map for the generation of random names.

Comment: @ASAkram, Depending on what the OP means by "this weekend" and "last weekend," It seems likely that the OP wants subsequent executions of the program to remember what was generated by previous executions. They're going to need a file or a database for that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes I thought so. Maybe he/she wants to check for all the possible combinations and in that case https://stackoverflow.com/a/67922682/14115415 this answer will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need it to generate the names based on **last weekend** check, if the generated name matches with last weekend's generated name then the program to run again to generate different name.

If this doesn't work for you it may give you some ideas.

- choose two names at random to be weekend names.
- remove those names from future use.
- next time, choose new names from available list
- add back the old names
- and update the current names in use.

Now two names will appear in adjacent rows as the currently used names are printed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class WeekEndCheck {
    
    List<String> lastWeekendNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> availableNames = new LinkedList<>(
        Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five"));
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WeekEndCheck().start();
    }
    
    public void start() {
        // do it for 10 weekends, not two names should
        // appear adjacent to each other
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            setWeekEndNames();
            System.out.println("Weekend " + (i+1) + " " + lastWeekendNames);
        }
    }
    
    Random r = new Random();
    
    public void setWeekEndNames() {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            int indx = r.nextInt(availableNames.size());
            temp.add(availableNames.remove(indx));
        }
        availableNames.addAll(lastWeekendNames);
        lastWeekendNames.clear();
        lastWeekendNames.addAll(temp);
    }
}
```

Prints something like this

```
Weekend 1 [three, one]
Weekend 2 [two, four]
Weekend 3 [five, one]
Weekend 4 [two, four]
Weekend 5 [one, three]
Weekend 6 [five, four]
Weekend 7 [three, two]
Weekend 8 [one, four]
Weekend 9 [two, five]
Weekend 10 [one, three]
```

**Update**

To permit the same name on both Saturday and Sunday but not be used the following weekend, this should work.  It is similar to the other except:

- the indices are saved and conditionally removed after the names have been selected.
- if the two indices are the same, only one name is removed so it can't be used the following weekend
- otherwise, to keep the list in sync, first remove the larger index number, then remove the smaller.  Otherwise, the wrong one could get removed or an exception could be thrown.

```
public void setWeekEndNames() {
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] indices = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        indices[i] = r.nextInt(availableNames.size());
        temp.add(availableNames.get(indices[i]));
    }
    if (indices[0] == indices[1]) {
        availableNames.remove(indices[0]);
    } else {
        availableNames.remove(Math.max(indices[0], indices[1]));
        availableNames.remove(Math.min(indices[0], indices[1]));
    }
    availableNames.addAll(lastWeekendNames);
    lastWeekendNames.clear();
    lastWeekendNames.addAll(temp);
}
```

Comment: I am unable to add the names to LinkedList with "List.of"(LinkedList<>(
            List.of). Instead i tried to add the names in later method and i get the output as below:                                                                                                                           
Weekend 1 [one, four]
Weekend 2 [two, three]
Weekend 3 [three, three]
Weekend 4 [one, one]
Weekend 5 [four, four]
Weekend 6 [two, four]
Weekend 7 [one, two]
Weekend 8 [three, three]
Weekend 9 [one, four]
Weekend 10 [three, four]

Comment: `List.of` was introduced in Java 9 so you may be running an older version of Java.  But you should not be getting two of the same name for a weekend.  Are you certain you did this as in my example `temp.add(availableNames.remove(indx));`  It removes the value so it can't be reused for that weekend.

Comment: Oh, i am executing in 1.8 jre. But i am doing the temp.add same as your example. Here is a link to online editor of the program i'm running : https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/3o6d

Comment: I found the problem.  You keep adding the same names to the `availableNames` list in the  method.  Don't do that.  They need to be added outside of that. and only once  You can use `Arrays.asList` which will do the same thing as `List.of()`

Comment: I did the exact same thing as you. But still i see a different output (Like if i give "one,"two","three","four" as an input then i get "two","four" for Weekend 1, Weekend 3 repeatedly. Please check the program and output here: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/eDB

Comment: I just ran  your code.  It works as it should (assuming I understand your requirements).  But the nature of randomness with such a small number of names means that you could get what you say.   In your case every other time you will always have the same two names from which to choose because the others were used the previous weekend.  Their order is the only thing that could be different.  Please try adding some more names to the original list.  But if that doesn't work like you want then I must not be doing what you expect.  Regards.

Comment: I think i get it now. Thank you for patiently helping with this question, really appreciate that. Also, what change do i need to make in case i want "one" to be generated both on Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: That specific name or just the same name for Saturday and Sunday?

Comment: The same name for Saturday and Sunday, so the output might look like : Weekend1: [one,one] , Weekend2:[two,two],Weekend3:[four,four] .So, basically i am trying to generate the names monthly(In a month there are four weekends).Again next month same set of output: Weekend1: [one,one] , Weekend2:[two,two],Weekend3:[four,four] .Hope, i'm clear.

Comment: Gotit!  I believe my updated answer will work.

Comment: I get something like this: Weekend 1 [four, one]
Weekend 2 [three, two]
Weekend 3 [one, four]
Weekend 4 [three, three]
Weekend 5 [four, two]
Weekend 6 [three, three]
Weekend 7 [two, four]
Weekend 8 [three, three]
Weekend 9 [three, two]
Weekend 10 [four, one] . Is "Random" class creating this issue?
Here is the link: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/eGj

Comment: It doesn't force the issue.  It simply lets it happen.  So if you have lots of names, it is unlikely it will occur.

Comment: I just have four/three names with which i need to run the program.

Comment: I copied your code and it ran okay.  Perhaps you are accidentally running the wrong version or something or it didn't compile.  Put a print message in the method to guarantee you are running the new version.  Other than that, I have no idea the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by running a while loop until the generated string does not match your unwanted strings.

For example:

```
String[] names = new String[]{"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
String[] lastWeekend = new String[]{"one", "three"}; // you should get these from somewhere else

Random rd = new Random();

int x = rd.nextInt(names.length);

// using a list for convenience
while(Arrays.asList(lastWeekend).contains(names[x]))
{
    x = rd.nextInt(names.length);
}

// names[x] will now be "two", "four" or "five"
```